# When is the flurry power triggered?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

As I have read, it is possible to use the flurry power as soon as I hit. So when using Crane's Wings, I can use the flurry before pushing the enemy.

But what when I attack multiple targets? When can I use the flurry then? Right after the first hit is resolved or at the end of the attack?

E.g. the Leopard Maneuvre: Can I use the flurry power after hitting the first enemy or only after the complete attack is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens during the `Hit` line resolution on the power.

All of the Flurry of Blows powers have the same trigger:

> You hit with an attack during your turn.

Powers are resolved in the order they appear on the card. So, let's say you take a basic Monk attack like Fallen Needle. It has the following lines:

- Target
- Attack
- Hit

You determine whether or not you hit something during the `Attack` line. However, you Hit someone during the `Hit` line. So Flurry of blows will trigger during this stage. For powers that attack multiple enemies, you can wait until the end of the damage resolution stage. If the power is a multi attack, you'll have to decide whether to use it during the first damage resolution or wait and see if you hit on the subsequent attacks.